# Placing package in existing Utilities` context has odd paraellelization effect

Tags: packages, parallelization

I noticed this in V.10 but possibly it was in effect in V.9.

I have a package which in simplified form looks like:-

```
BeginPackage["Utilities`DataHandling`"];
f;
Begin["`Private`"];
f[data_List] := Module[{samples, selectFrom},
    selectFrom[]:=($KernelID->data);
     DistributeDefinitions[selectFrom];
     samples = ParallelTable[$KernelID->Apply[Hold,{"CTUDH",$Context, Context[selectFrom], selectFrom[]}], {10}, Method -> "CoarsestGrained"];
    samples
    ];
End[];
EndPackage[];
```

The actual package is much bigger and performed a useful function, the payload in ParallelTable here is to illustrate the problem.

When f is executed, the local symbol **selectFrom** is given a definition and distributed to all sub-kernels.

Except that its not (when the package is loaded via Needs).  So far as the sub-kernels are concerned the symbol **selectFrom** has no definition so the call **selectFrom** results in **Utilities`DataHandling`Private`selectFromXXX**[] - the *Hold* prevents this from evaluating in the master kernel on return.  Try f[{1,2,3}].

Changing the package name to MyUtilities`DataHandling` or indeed anything else resolves this and **selectFrom** is correctly defined in all the sub-kernels.  This only took a day or so to work out *sigh*.

What is special about the (admittedly Built-in) context Utilities?  How does it mess up *DistributeDefintions*?